# How to mock Config data of 'react-native-config' library in react native using Jest?

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Here I am trying to get the environment details to fetch the base url of the application. [Here is the package being used](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config).

// configfile.ts

```
import Config from 'react-native-config';

interface Setting {
  environment: string;
 
}
const settings: Setting = {
  environment: Config.ENV || '',

};

export default settings;
```

Now whenever I am trying to access `settings.environment` from my test file , it is returning empty string('') because the value of `Config.ENV` is undefined as I am not able to mock the value.

**Excepted Result :** Whenever I will call `settings.environment` , I should get **'test'** as returned string value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Jest**

For mocking the Config.ENV usage, create a folder `__mocks__` at root of your project and create a file inside named `react-native-config.js`

inside the file paste below code

// react-native-config.js

```
export default {
  ENV: 'test', // here 'test' is expected value
};
```